# I am getting script Error when try to compare expected value with incorrect value. if I compare it with correct value it will give correct result data

Tags: javascript, postman

I am getting test script Error (not getting the test results) (see 1st image)   when try to compare expected value with incorrect value. if I compare it with correct value it will give correct result data (see the 2nd image)

error code :

```
    pm.test("Row : " + i + " - " + dataArr[1] + " :  Verify symbol Instrument type with DB", function () {
        var insTypeRes = dataArr[2];
        var intInsType = parseInt(insTypeRes);
        console.log("insType " + intInsType);


        pm.sendRequest("http://192.168.xx.xxx:8080/ords/unidata/symbol/symbol/" + dataArr[1], function (err, response) {
            var resBoday = response.json()
            var insTypeDB = resBoday.items[0].instrument_type_id;
            var intInsTypeDB = parseInt(insTypeDB);
            console.log("insTypeDB " + intInsTypeDB);
            pm.expect(intInsTypeDB).is.to.equals(61);

        });
        
    });
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Code and errors should be posted here as **text**.

Comment: Isn't this normal? If `expect` is an assertion, and behaves like Chai as suggested in  [`expect` docs](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/) ("Refer to the Chai Docs for a complete overview of assertion syntax options") then it will throw if it you compare a wrong value with the expected value, perhaps with the error message in the circled text. Perhaps, maybe?

Comment: but why it is not coming to my Test Results??

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#sending-requests-from-scripts) for `pm.test` suggests that testing an asynchronous result should call a `done` callback passed to the test function as an argument, and a call to `done` be made after the assertion.

**However**, while you are welcome to try it, the chance of this being able to include a *failed* test in `Test Results` is potentially non-existent: if the `expect` assertion throws, a `done()` call placed after it never gets executed.

This [postman blog article](https://blog.postman.com/send-asynchronous-requests-with-postmans-pm-api/) contains an example headed

```
  // example containing a test ** under the Tests tab only
```

which suggests that to log the failure under Test Results, change the `expect` assertion in the request callback function,

```
pm.expect(intInsTypeDB).is.to.equals(61);
```

into a `pm.test` definition:

```
pm.test("Row : " + i + " - " + dataArr[1] + " : Instrument type is valid", function() {
    pm.expect(intInsTypeDB).is.to.equals(61);
});
```

If you try this, make sure that the loop variable `i` is declared with `let` and not `var` so that the name string passed to `pm.test` contains the correct value of `i`.

---

To answer the question in comments, at the moment the test function returns without throwing an error (the call back is called after the network request has been performed), so the catch clause of a `try/catch` block the runner places around the test function call will not be triggered.

Postman appears to have added a global `error` handler to catch and report assertion errors that were not otherwise caught. Hence the

> There was an error in evaluating the test script: ...

error message appears on the console and not in Test Results because the test function that the (anonymous) function raising the error is nested within is unknown.